# What's going on with this credit rating question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In [This question here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13025/how-do-i-overcome-my-credit-rating-in-reference-to-applying-for-jobs), the OP is asking about how to mitigate the impact having a low credit score has on getting a job.  An odd question, but one that could potentially be applicable to many people (especially in today's economy).  It has, however, gained one downvote and three closure requests.

One of the closure requests I could accept, even if I don't fully agree with it.  The question could be interpreted as an opinion-based one.  However, the two clove votes for it being a "legal" related question baffle me.

Is this actually a legal matter i'm not noticing?  And how could we better shape this question to help people out more significantly?

edit: the question has now been closed due to the legal reason.

Comment: I think this question falls into the "This question is too hard to answer with out thinking so I am going to vote to close" Category.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand where the legal issue is. The question is basically:

`I have an issue that at first glance may cause a potential employer to reject me, it won't be found on my resume and isn't illegal but it will show up if they do a background check. How and when should I address it?`

It could be a bankruptcy; low credit score; that my first spouse was an axe murderer; that somebody with my same name is wanted by the FBI.

They don't want help fixing their credit report, or paying off the debt. They want to know how to overcome the hurdle.

The question for the HR exports and hiring mangers is, how have potential employees addressed the issue?

Comment: exactly my point.  i don't like the reason given for the close, and have voted to reopen.